# On python, how do I compare CurrentValue to previousValue and output max

Tags: python, loops, arduino, compare, adc

I have always used Arduino IDE but now, I am using MuEditor.
I used Arduino IDE and it was easier to compare the current value to its previous value, and output max value after a certain period. Code from the Arduino is shown below.

```
int sample1 = 0; 
void loop() {
  int sensorValue = 0;
  sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
    if (sensorValue > sample1) {
      sample1 = sensorValue;
    }
  }
  Serial.println(sample1 * (5.0 / 1023.0));
}
```

I want to use the same concept on Mu Editor, and I cannot seems to get it done right.
I would like to continuously compare the current value to previous value and output max value after certain period.  This is what I came up with on MuEditor. I would appreciate your help on this.

```
import time
import board
from analogio import AnalogIn

analog_in = AnalogIn(board.A1)
Sample = 0


def get_voltage(pin):
    return (pin.value * 3.3) / 65536


while True:
    for x in range(1000):
        if Sample < analog_in:
            Sample = analog_in
    print((get_voltage(Sample1),))
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Result:

[image: Display of Code with Result]

Comment: What is the output that you get? Shouldn't you be getting the analog reading doing analog_in = AnalogIn(board.A1) at every iteration inside the for loop? I believe that you are missing that...

Comment: Currently the output I am getting are values that is continuous read from Pin A1.  What I want on the output is the continuous update of max value from the Analog Input reading. For example: if the Analog Input reads 3V, it outputs 3V continuously until it sees  higher voltage. It will then output higher voltage continuously. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [circuitpython](https://circuitpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shared-bindings/analogio/)'s `analogio.AnalogIn()` you need to refer to the `.value` property of the `AnalogIn` instance

```py
import analogio
with analogio.AnalogIn(board.A1) as pin_sensor:
    pin_sensor.value  # voltage
# pin_sensor is closed when leaving the above scope
```

Just get the `max()` at each loop if you're discarding the other values

```py
...
result = 0
with analogio.AnalogIn(board.A1) as pin_sensor:
    for x in range(..):
        result = max(result, pin_sensor.value)
print(result)
```

However, note that *especially with electronics*, you more likely want a more complex mechanism-

- collect frequently enough to catch the frequency of what you're sampling (see [Nyquist-Shannon theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem)), ideally as often as you can (however, if you have a collection of digital logic, this may be infeasible, or drive a faster processor choice, etc.)
- carefully discard outliers (which can be transients/static/contact bounce..)
- refer to a moving average (take the average of the last N samples)
- collect with a [precise timer and interrupt](https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-2/timers) (such that your sampling rate isn't dependent on unrelated logic)